# Flutter windows app crashes after start up, geolocator 9.0.1

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, crash, geolocator

Flutter windows app crashes after start up, i'm using geolocator 9.0.1, tried 8.0.1. Web, ios, android works fine. No errors shown

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: No errors, just crash

Comment: Would you please [edit] your question and include a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so other users are able to find an answer for you.

Comment: [github](https://github.com/ZagrebaBogdan/ClimaFlutter), try windows app

Comment: [It's working fine here](https://imgur.com/2PTgFeR) on my Windows machine. Can you try `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get` and run again? Also, what's the output of `flutter doctor -v`?

Comment: Hmm, didn't help, doctor says everything is ok, no issues found

Comment: Haha, it's cool that it works for others at least))

Comment: What's the Visual Studio Community version? 2022?

Comment: Yes (can't answer with less than 15 symbols)

Answer (score 0):

you need to turn on location,if no permission handler setup is done else it seems to crash in windows